# Polar coordinates with imaginary radius

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is it possible to construct a mathematical space described by polar coordinates with the real angles and imaginary radius? In the simplest case of just two dimensions, one real angle and the imaginary radius (or vice versa, the real radius and at least one imaginary angle). I don't think so, but if possible, I'd appreciate any reference or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

> "The radius is a scalar quantity which is fully described by its magnitude. It is defined as the distance between center and any point on the circumference of a circle".

On a complex plane, the value of the distance between two points, whether they have imaginary parts or not can be described with real numbers. For example, 2i is 3 distance units away from 5i, etc. When using Pythagoras's Theorem to find the distance between two points, all units are squared (i.e made positive) and then added before being squared rooted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and taking time to respond! To clarify, I am not talking specifically about the complex plane.I am not putting any conditions on the space (such as the distance between two points being positive real, etc.). The only conditions are that the radius is imaginary and the angle is real. Would this define a space (in a general sense) or be a logical contradiction? I believe the latter, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @safesphere I used the complex plane to make things simpler for a circle, which can be constructed from 'slicing' a plane (2D) out of space (3D). Things are complicated with complex space as the 3rd axis (after Re. axis and Im. axis) is ambiguous; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_space. The radius cannot be complex, as it is calculated using the *x* and *y* from *x + yi*, which are both real numbers. The imaginary unit is disregarded. Furthermore, the radius is scalar: a "one-component quantity". Complex numbers are vectors with two components. Even '5i' is short for '0 + 5i'.

Comment: A radius is essentially a distance. So can there be a space where a distance between any two points is a complex number? I do not necessarily disagree with you, as I also didn't think it was possible. I am just not convinced that we have a sufficient logic to say definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

I think such a visualization is an intriguing possibility. I have wondered about the possibility of labling each point(r,θ) on the polar plane as either r + iθ or as ir + θ. After all, there is nothing about complex numbers which says they must be represented as a real and imaginary number on the cartesian plane. However, algebraic operations with complex numbers on these two polar planes will be visually different from the conventional (Cartesian) representation of complex numbers.

Comment: What would be the metric?

Comment: The modulus could provide a metric.

Comment: Would not having a metric make it worthless?

Comment: If we consider this space to be a metric space, then the metric would provide a mathematical definition of this space. If this space is not a metric space, then it would need to be mathematically defined in some other way. Your formula is merely a restatement of the question, but not an answer that would clarify if this space is meaningful, if this definition is logical and sufficient, or what the basic properties of this space are. Including if this is a metric space and, if so, what its metric is, or if it is not a metric space, then what kind of space it is.